# System time not updating while screen is locked

Tags: date-and-time

Device: [ASUS MemoPad 7 (K013)](https://www.asus.com/Tablets/ASUS_MeMO_Pad_7_ME176C/), running the latest ASUS ROM based on Android Lollipop 5.0 (updated automatically with the included ASUS updater).

When I lock the screen, the system time stops ticking until I unlock it again.
**After unlocking, it does not update to current time**, instead lags behind for the amount of time it was locked.

- The time zone is set correctly and the device has stable Internet connection via Wi-Fi (no packet data option available on this device).
- The date/time update setting is set to "Use network time", which disables manual time adjustment. After unchecking "Use network time" I can set the time manually.

*Interestingly enough, after adjusting the time and re-enabling "Use network time", the time instantly skips back to the "lagged" value (how it was before manual adjustment).*

**Rebooting** the tablet forces a time update, although the problem keeps persisting on screen lock, which renders the system clock, and thus the device, useless for my purposes.

A similar problem used to occur for me on a different device, but the time was updating automatically a couple seconds after unlocking. This is not the case here.

Please advise.

Comment: It seems this is a known issue with ASUS MemoPad. [XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/memo-pad-7/general/asus-memo-7-me176cx-t2814046/post61491802#post61491802) mentions to clear system cache or wipe with stock recovery, [AndroidCentral Forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/asus-memo-pad-hd7/547786-asus-memo-pad-7-losing-time.html) mentions the probability of [network time sync sets wrong time](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39951#makechanges). No clear solution as of now though.

Comment: And [AOSP Issue Tracker on the same issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9974)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wiping cache with stock recovery](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-htc-one/315416-how-clear-cache-partition-stock-recovery-un-rooted-phone.html) seems to have solved it for me.

> Power off phone (be sure to turn off fast reboot in settings first). Boot into recovery by holding volume-down key and then holding power key until boot menu appears. Volume down to RECOVERY and tap power to select. HTC logo appears followed by a blank, dim screen. Wait about 30 seconds for red triangle icon to appear.
>
> Now, hold down volume-up and tap power button. Recovery menu appears. Volume-down to "Wipe cache partition" at bottom of list and tap power key. Cache gets cleared. Then select "reboot system now" by tapping power key again. Done!

Comment: What is the reason I'm being downvoted when this method solved my problem?

Comment: Well sometimes the community is real harsh to downvote without giving the reason. I hate that kind of behavior too. Discourage people despite their effort. Back to this question, I'm looking for a solution to this very problem. Although it "seems" to work for you (you observed for long enough? until now still works?), I did a dirty flash yesterday but the problem persists. The time is only 5-10 minutes off though, but it's still bugging me :).

Comment: Issue's been gone for me ever since, actively using the tablet on various ways day-to-day. Thanks for your reply.